# Replace a word with another set of strings in a UNIX file

Tags: sed

When I try to replace a string using sed command it works perfectly fine.
For eg :

When i used the below sed command:

```
sed 's/DB_ALTER/DB_REPRISE/g' /product/dwhrec1/abc.ksh > /product/dwhrec1/abc1.ksh
```

This command works perfectly fine and replace all the "DB_ALTER" with "DB_REPRISE" and writes the result to abc1.ksh script.

But when I place all such values in a file. for eg:

```
cat Repla.txt
DB_ALTER
DB_CMD
DB_GEST_COMM
```

```
for i in `cat Repla.txt`
do
sed 's/$i/DB_REPRISE/g' /product/dwhrec1/abc.ksh > /product/dwhrec1/abc1.ksh
done
```

But this does not work. In my file Repla.txt is just an example. In actual it has many values.
Can anyone please help me on this command or suggest some alternative.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your script.  The first is that the `$i` variable appears within single quotes.  That means that bash will not substitute for the value of `i`.  It needs to be in double-quotes.

Secondly, every time that you run `sed`, it overwrites the previous abc1.ksh file.  You should copy `abc.ksh` to `abc1.ksh` and then modify in place `abc1.ksh` as many times as needed:

```sh
cp abc.ksh abc1.ksh
for i in `cat Repla.txt`; do 
    sed -i'' "s/$i/DB_REPRISE/g" abc1.ksh
done
```

The `-i` flag to `sed` causes it to modify the file in place.

Also, bash will apply word splitting to `cat Repla.txt`.  This can surprise people who were expecting it to work line-by-line, not word-by-word.

#### Workaround in case your `sed` does not support `-i`

The `sed` on both [linux (GNU)](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and [Mac OSX (BSD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) support `-i`.  If your `sed` does not, try:

```
cmd=
for i in `cat Repla.txt`; do
    [ "$cmd" ] && cmd="$cmd;"
    cmd="$cmd s/$i/DB_REPRISE/g"
done
sed  "$cmd" abc.ksh >abc1.ksh
```

The above puts all the substitution commands that you need in a single shell variable.  This way, `sed` only needs to be run once and `-i` is not used.

#### Another option

If it is acceptable to overwrite the source file, then:

```
for i in $(cat Repla.txt)
do
    sed 's/'$i'/DB_REPRISE/g' abc.ksh >abc1.ksh
    mv -f abc1.ksh abc.ksh
done
```

The above puts in single quotes all of the `sed` command except for the part that we want the shell to expand.  This is not needed in this example but could be useful if your replacement text had shell-active characters.  The above also uses the more modern `$(...)` in place of backquotes for command substitution.

If `$i` were to contain spaces (it doesn't here), we would need to enclose it in double-quotes to protect it against shell word splitting as in:

```
for i in $(cat Repla.txt)
do
    sed 's/'"$i"'/DB_REPRISE/g' abc.ksh >abc1.ksh
    mv -f abc1.ksh abc.ksh
done
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But I am getting the below issue :

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But I am getting the below issue : dwhrec1@iu0469:/home/dwhrec1 #for i in `cat Repla.txt`
==> do
==> sed -i'' "s/$i/DB_REPRISE/g" /product/dwhrec1/DSAlim_WUSG_RGR_USG_PA_BIOS_MF_0739.ksh
==> done
sed: illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] script [file...]
        sed [-n] [-e script]...[-f script_file]...[file...]
sed: illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] script [file...]
        sed [-n] [-e script]...[-f script_file]...[file...]

Comment: @user3568369 Sorry about that.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @user3568369 That is unusual: the `sed` on both Mac and Linux support `-i`.  I added an alternative that avoids `-i`.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi ,
When I tried the below command it works perfectly fine :)

dwhrec1@iu0469:/home/dwhrec1 #for i in `cat Repla.txt`

==> do

==> sed 's/'`echo $i`'/DB_REPRISE/g' /product/dwhrec1/abc.ksh > /product/dwhrec1/abc1.ksh

==> mv -f /product/dwhrec1/abc1.ksh /product/dwhrec1/abc.ksh

==> done

Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: @user3568369 Very good.  I added the better parts of that to the answer.